# Finding moments of compounding normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose that given $\Theta=\theta$, X is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $v$ so that $$f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi v}} \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2v}(x-\theta)^2\right];  -\infty <x<\infty$$

and $\Theta$ itself is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $a$ i.e.

$$f_{\Theta}(\theta)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a}} \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2a}(\theta-\mu)^2\right];  -\infty <\theta<\infty$$

How can one determine the marginal distribution function of $X$, the probability density function of $X$, and hence the $var(X)$?

Using the answer given by **Tommik**  below, I was also able to give more details derivations below

From definition of marginal distribution, we have $$f_X(x)=\int _{\forall \theta} f_{X| \Theta}f_{\Theta} \ d  \theta$$
That is we consider \begin{align*}
  f_{X| \Theta}f_{\Theta} &=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{va}}\exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2v}(x-\theta)^2-\dfrac{1}{2a}(\theta-\mu)^2\right)
  \end{align*}
Simplifying the expression inside, we have
\begin{align*}
  f_{X| \Theta}f_{\Theta} &=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{va}}\exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2v}(x-\theta)^2-\dfrac{1}{2a}(\theta-\mu)^2\right) \\
  &= \dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{va}}\exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2va} \left( a (x-\theta)^2+v(\theta-\mu)^2 \right) \right)\\
  &=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{va}}\exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2va} \left( a (x-\theta)^2+v(\theta-\mu)^2 \right) \right) \\
  &=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{va}}\exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2va} \left( ax^2+v\mu^2+(a+v)\theta^2-2\theta (ax+\mu v) \right) \right) \\
  \end{align*}
Now, we complete the square about $ \theta $ and about $\mu$, we have
\begin{align*}
  f_{X| \Theta}f_{\Theta}&=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{va}}\exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2va} \left( ax^2+v\mu^2+(a+v)\theta^2-2\theta (ax+\mu v) \right) \right) \\
  &=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{va}}\exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2va} \left( M+(a+v) \left(\theta-\frac{ax+\mu v}{a+v} \right)^2 \right) \right)
  \end{align*}
Where $ M=ax^2+v\mu^2-\dfrac{(ax+\mu v)^2}{a+v}= \dfrac{av(x-\mu)^2}{a+v} $\

Thus, we have \begin{align*}
   f_{X| \Theta}f_{\Theta}&=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{va}}\exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2va} \left( \dfrac{av(x-\mu)^2}{a+v}+(a+v) \left(\theta-\frac{ax+\mu v}{a+v} \right)^2 \right) \right)
  \end{align*}
Hence, we substitute this in the integral above and we have \begin{align*}
 & \int _{\forall \theta }  f_{X| \Theta}f_{\Theta} \ d \theta \\ &=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{va}}\exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2}  \dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{a+v}   \right) \int _{\forall \theta  } \exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2va} \left( (a+v) \left(\theta-\frac{ax+\mu v}{a+v} \right)^2 \right) \right) \ d \theta
  \end{align*}
Letting $ t= \theta-\frac{ax+\mu v}{a+v} \Rightarrow dt=d \theta$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \int _{\forall \theta }  f_{X| \Theta}f_{\Theta} \ d \theta &=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{va}}\exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2}  \dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{a+v}   \right) \int _{\forall \theta  } \exp\left( -\frac{t^2(a+v)}{2va}  \right) \ d \theta
  \end{align*}
Letting $ y=\dfrac{t\sqrt{a+v}}{\sqrt{va}}  \Rightarrow dt=\dfrac{\sqrt{va}}{\sqrt{a+v}} dy$, we can write
\begin{align*}
 \int _{\forall \theta }  f_{X| \Theta}f_{\Theta} \ d \theta &=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{va}} \dfrac{\sqrt{va}}{\sqrt{a+v}}\exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2}  \dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{a+v}   \right) \int _{\forall \theta  } \exp\left( -\frac{y^2}{2}  \right) \ d y \\
 &= \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi(v+a)}} \exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2}  \dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{a+v}   \right) \int _{\forall \theta  } \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left( -\frac{y^2}{2}  \right) \ d y \\
\Rightarrow f_X(x) &= \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi(v+a)}} \exp\left( -\dfrac{1}{2}  \dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{a+v}   \right)
  \end{align*}
This is the pdf of $ N(\mu, a+v) $

Hence, $ \mathbb{V}ar(X)=a+v $

Comment: by the way, $X|\theta$ is normally distributed with mean $\theta$...you wrote $\mu$

Comment: $f_X(x)=\int f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta)f_{\Theta}(\theta)\,d\theta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there is a typo in your question so that

$$X|\theta\sim N(\theta;v)$$

and $\theta$ itself is gaussian

$$\theta\sim N(\mu;a)$$

Is it easy to prove that marginally

$$X\sim N(\mu;a+v)$$

---

**Proof:**

---

Let's set

$$Y=X-\theta$$

The conditional law $Y|\theta$ is obviously $N(0;v)$ , $\forall{\theta}$ and thus $Y\perp\!\!\!\perp \theta$

This means that

$$X=Y+\theta$$

is a linear combination of two independent gaussians and thus $X$ itself is Gaussian with the following parameters:

$$X\sim N(\mu;a+v)$$

Comment: Can you give simpler proof even if it is long @tommik

Comment: @PatrickChidzalo:  keep calm and read carefully  my proof: I am sure you will understand it and then you will find it very easy. An alterantive way is to multiply the 2 densities and integrate in $\Theta$ after some algebraic manipulations...but it  is wasted time, IMHO